# Custom Recipes in Minecraft Modpack

Tags: minecraft-modding

I want to have a new Recipe with crafttweaker, which using machines from the create mod, for Netherrack like this [image: Compacting Netherrack]

At the moment I tryed this code in \scripts\MyRecipes.zs:

```
import crafttweaker.api.item.IItemStack;
import crafttweaker.api.ingredient.IIngredient;
import crafttweaker.api.recipe.FurnaceRecipeManager;

import mods.create.IProcessingRecipeManager;
import mods.create.MechanicalCrafterManager;
import mods.create.CrushingManager;
import mods.create.SplashingManager;
import mods.create.CompactingManager;
import mods.create.FillingManager;
import mods.create.MixingManager;
import mods.create.PressingManager;



<recipetype:create:compacting>.addRecipe("compact_netherrack", <constant:create:heat_condition:none>, [<item:minecraft:netherrack> * 8], [<item:minecraft:cobblestone> * 8, <item:minecraft:nether_wart>], [<fluid:minecraft:lava> * 10], 100);
```

but when I go into the world I get this errors:

```
[Error] Parser Exception @ MyRecipes.zs:16:63 : Invalid bracket expression: no prefix constant
[Error] Scripts are invalid!
[Error] Parser Exception @ MyRecipes.zs:16:63 : Invalid bracket expression: no prefix constant
[Error] Scripts are invalid!
```

[image: errors]

can somebody help me?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but a causal search suggests posting the `crafttweaker.log` file (or maybe a portion thereof), might be an easier way to post error messages as text. [More info on log file here](https://docs.blamejared.com/1.18/en/tutorial/IntroductionToScripting/TheCraftTweakerLogFile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error text, I'm guessing that the problem is this part `<constant:create:heat_condition:none>` as it says "Invalid bracket expression: no prefix constant", I figured that `<constant:...>` is not a thing, or at least not valid here.

Thus, I decided to search the line up to that point, to see an example of how it should be. And I found it here: [Create Compacting](https://docs.blamejared.com/1.16/en/mods/Create/Compacting). Based on that I believe you should write `"none"` instead of `<constant:create:heat_condition:none>`. As far as I can tell that is all the fixing required.